# Send email to multiple users with query and with unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sendmail

I am trying to send an email to users from a mysql query and include another column (employee) in the $message (body) of the email that matches that row from the table:

So bob@test.com should get an email only with `employee1,employee2,employee3 in email..etc...

This script instead will email all the rows in each email.

```
 `employee | email`
 `employee1,employee2,employee3 | bob@test.com`
 `employee4,employee5,employee6 | steve@test.com`
 `employee7,employee8,employee9 | jim@test.com`

Script:
mysql_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Joomla") or die(mysql_error());

$query = sprintf("select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(e.`name`)) AS employee, 
m.name as manager, email, r.week,r.year,r.manager_approved, r.Date
from peg_users e
left JOIN peg_users m ON e.manager = m.id
left JOIN project_tracker_tool_finance_report r ON m.id = r.manager
where e.project_tracker_user = 1 AND r.manager_approved = 'NO' 
AND CONCAT(r.year,r.week,'') = YEARWEEK(NOW()) -2
GROUP BY m.name
order by m.name
limit 2");
//$email = "to@domain.com"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$email = $row['email'];
$from_email = "masked";
$emailcc = "masked"; 
//$emailcc = "";
$subject = "Project Time Tracker - Employees Overdue"; 
$headers = "From: $from_email" . "\r\n" . "CC: $emailcc"; 

$body .= " \n "
."Following are the people whoes subscription will expire tomorrow"." \n "." 
\n "
."First Name : ".$row['employee']." \n "
."\n". "\n". "==============================". "\n"; 
} 

// send email 
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

$send = mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers); 
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also if this is a Joomla install, why can't you do this through the Joomla API?